# Elegant way to inject custom hook into evolve function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, react-hooks, ramda.js

My team and I strongly incorporate FP and react-hooks patterns on a daily basis, though sometimes we struggle how to manage hooks together with pure functions. Recently, we're meeting a lot of situations where hook "callback" has to be somewhere inside the `compose` or another transformer - in this case, it's `evolve` function  e.g:

```js
const getDefinedActions = R.filter(
      R.both(isActionDefined, R.ifElse(hasAfterConfirm, isAfterConfirmDefined, R.T))
    )
    
const translateTitles = R.map(
  R.evolve({
    title: title => useTranslate()(title)
  })
)

export const useActions = R.compose(
  translateTitles,
  getDefinedActions
)
```

In the example above we want to filter actions out based on some predicates + add translations, which require the usage of `useTranslate` hook. Unfortunately we can't just write `useTranslate()` over there, because the hook has to be initialized after the React component is mounted. What've done so far in those situations:

- create the hook function "on fly", and pass it to another ramda's function. e.g `{ const translate = useTranslate(); return R.compose(..., translate, ...) }` - we don't like this aproach because we can't incorporate point-free style while doing this ;/
- another way is to call hook in the anonymous function in the same way that I've wrote in the snippet above. - although we don't have to write the whole function block and declare an additional variable we don't like this approach either because we feel like all the time we have to redundantly write the arguments that are passed over: `arg => hook()(arg)`

Is there any general approach in FP to handle that kind of issue where we have to inject the function, which has to be lazily evaluated and then based on that result we can conduct other calculations? Maybe even `Ramda` itself has the function, which helps to inject specific behavior, so we could use it like that:

```
R.evolve({
  title: R.useWith(useTranslate, R.identity) // arg => useTranslate()(R.identity(arg))
})
```

PS. I know there is a function called `useWith` in Ramda, but it works in a different way ;/

Any help's gonna be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I entirely understand your question.  Are you simply looking for a way to do that initialization of `useTranslate` only once?  If so, then I don't think Ramda has anything built in, but it would be easy enough to write something like

```js
const dethunk = (fn) => {
  let initialized = null;
  return (...args) => (initialized || (initialized = fn())) (...args)
}
```

and then write something like.

```
const translateTitles = map (evolve ({title: dethunk(useTranslate) }))
```

And if you wanted to pass parameters to the initialization you could change it to

```js
const dethunk = (fn, ...initialArgs) => {
  let initialized = null;
  return (...args) => (initialized || (initialized = fn(...initialArgs))) (...args)
}

const foo = (a, b) => {
  console.log(`Initializing with '${a}' and '${b}'`)
  return (c) => `foo('${a}', '${b}', ${c})`
}

const bar = dethunk(foo, 'x', 'y')

console.log('Have not initialized yet');

console .log (bar (1))
console .log (bar (2))
console .log (bar (3))
```

Does that do what you need?